# Broken makemigrations in django

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

I added I new app in django project. After that I made a migration and migrate on it. Then I changed some field in model, and after trying to create some instance it was mistake with this field. So after that I made I terrible mistake and delete all migrations in this app, and now I can't make new migrations.

I have such error: "Migration ... dependences reference nonexistent parent node" some where in old app. But this migration is exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to delete a migration you should run reverse migrations before deleting a migration. So if you're on migration 0004 and you made a mistake in that and wanted to go back, run the reverse to the previous migration e.g.

```
python manage.py migrate myapp 0003
```

This brings the database tables for `myapp` to the state they were in for migration 0003.

If you wanted to correct something, or re-create an initial migration for a feature you're making and you don't need to keep the test data you've created you should run;

```
python manage.py migrate myapp zero
```

This will run the backwards migration on all migrations for `myapp` including the initial migration.

If you've deleted all your migration files and you now want to do something with migrations for that app you'll have to delete the tables in the database relating to your app, then remove the rows from the migrations table (`django_migrations`) which relate to any migrations from your app and simply recreate the initial migration again.

The rows in the migrations table looks like this;

```
1   contenttypes    0001_initial    2015-04-16 10:09:38
```

So just look for your app name in that table.

Comment: Thank you. In future I will be very carefull with this. But now I still can not fix this problem. The migration try to find dependency which is exist. I tried to see the list of migrations to choose some stabble version, but I can't run any command Only thing I can is workng with shell. I just delete all tables with new module in DB.

Comment: @SergeyKostin If you've deleted the migration files already, removing the rows for those files in the migrations table will fix the issue as the system won't know the migrations ever existed. But to avoid database errors you also need to manually reverse the changes implemented by the migrations.